# C++ to C# porting

Tags: c#, c++

How can I port this code (c++) to c#?

```
template <class entity_type>
class State {
public:
    virtual void Enter(entity_type*) = 0;
    virtual void Execute(entity_type*) = 0;
    virtual void Exit(entity_type*) = 0;
    virtual ~State() { }
};
```

Comment: @lollancf37 That is what votes are for. Upvote the answers you think are good, and the asker will more likely have a look at them. Leaving comments like this doesn't help as much.

Comment: So, following on from various questions and assumptions made in the answers below, perhaps you could give us a few hints as to what `entity_type` might be, and how the `State` interface should operate upon it? Also, is `State` shown in its entirety here (eg, it is a purely abstract class) or does it contain concrete member variables or methods you've not shown?

Comment: I'm following the code on an IA programming book. Good text but pretty confusing sometimes. Part of the code is explained after many pages -.-

Comment: @Magnus Hoff I did upvote them. I agree that I do not reply to the question, that's why I commented on it rather than create a new answer. However you're right, I'll avoid that in the futur. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend that you read a tutorial or book to understand C++ basics, which will then make you understand the code yourself. Blindly translating pieces of code is not going to get you too far, as you might be missing the intention. Also, how much C# do you know? do you understand when and why to use the `IDisposable` interface? Do you know the difference between value and reference types (so that if someone translates into one of them you will be able to remap to the other if the rest of the code needs it?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that really is a purely abstract base class, which is what it looks like:

```
interface State<T>
{
    void Enter(T arg);
    void Execute(T arg);
    void Exit(T arg);
};
```

The exact argument passing convention is awkward though. Without knowing exactly what you want to do it is hard to say exactly what you should do in C#. Possibly, `void FunctionName(ref T arg)` might be more appropriate.

Comment: Possibly qualify the interface with  *where T : class* ?

Comment: Possibly, but that imposes an additional level of restriction and detail that is absent from the OP's question. The example code could work using a simple integral type as an index into some other datastructure, for example. I've tried to make a minimum of assumptions.

Answer (score 3):

Some thing of the sort:

```
interface State<T> : IDisposable
{
    void Enter(T t);
    void Execute(T t);
    void Exit(T t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class State<entity_type>
    {
        public abstract void Enter(entity_type obj);
        public abstract void Execute(entity_type obj);
        public abstract void Exit(entity_type obj);
    }
```

This seems to work :D

Comment: Does the `interface` solution not work? There are reasons that the highest voted answer uses `interface`. Perhaps you have additional constraints that you haven't mentioned? Anyway, you might want to not post your own answer, but rather accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: Certainly, using an interface would be the _canonical_ dot-net thing to do here. Remember a class can implement as many interfaces as you want/need, but it can only inherit from a single base class, abstract or otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

you can write like this

```
abstract class State<T> : IDisposable where T : EntityType
{
    public abstract void Enter(T t);
    public abstract void Execute(T t);
    public abstract void Exit(T t);

    public abstract void Dispose();
}
```

fix your T to EntityType class.

Comment: @Indeera, try out if you have doubt.

Comment: @Indeera try now. You should have to create one EntityType class